# How to force CDN-based MathJax to input with LaTeX math and output to MathML?

Tags: html, math, mathjax

I'd like to author some web pages using MathJax where I write LaTeX math formulas but force MathJax to output in MathML format. I know it can be done but I cannot figure out how to configure it to work in this manner. The documentation says to include the following in the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
```

and I am guessing that the `config` value is what I can use to force it. MathJax provides [other options](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/config-files.html#common-configurations) but none that fit my needs. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using a combined configuration file (specified in the `config=...` query), then you could set the output in your regular MathJax configuration, e.g., modifying the configuration underlying [the combined config's definition listed in your OP](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/config-files.html#the-tex-ams-chtml-configuration-file) might give you:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
 MathJax.Hub.Config({
   jax: ["input/TeX","output/NativeMML"], // instead of "output/CommonHTML"
   extensions: ["tex2jax.js","MathMenu.js","MathZoom.js", "AssistiveMML.js"],
   TeX: {
     extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js","noErrors.js","noUndefined.js"]
   }
 });
</script>
```

By just using this configuration, you lose the benefit of a *combined* config, namely that the TeX input Jax and Element Jax are combined into one file alongside the configuration options.

(Now you might be tempted to do override the output jax while using a combined configuration, e.g.,

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    jax: ["output/NativeMML"]
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML"></script>
```

but **that won't work** since the combined configurations load after the inline configuration.)

If you want to use a combined config but don't want to build one yourself, you have to overwrite it after the configuration, e.g.,

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("End Jax",function () {
  return MathJax.Hub.setRenderer("NativeMML");
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML"></script>
```

If you need more fine-grained control, check [the MathJax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output.html#automatic-selection-of-the-output-processor) for its browser-sniffing features.